# Why my script doesn't work on boot?

Tags: boot, bash, scripts

I have a simple bash script:

```
while [[ true ]]
do
    status="$(xset q | grep 'Monitor is Off')"
    if [[ $status != '' ]] ; then
        #shutdown the computer
        dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Poweroff" boolean:true
    fi
done
```

So whenever my screen get off my computer shutdown. This script work well, when i launch it from terminal, but I want to execute it every boot. I placed a symbolic link in rc5.d and seems to work. `pgrep poweroff` show script PID but, guess! if the screen get off pc don't shutdown. I don't undestand why.

Comment: Xset is a *user preferences* utility. Add it to startup applications (Dash > Startup Applications) and it will run on login as your user. It will work then.

Answer (score 1):

> ANALYSIS

Your script is started during boot, thus not following the login process, therefor it has no environment variables or perhaps a very limited set. I trust there is no DISPLAY, perhaps not even a PATH. So the **xset** command fails, **status** stays empty, the **dbus-send** never reached.
You can verify my explanation by changing the xset command in your script to:

> status="$(xset q 2>/tmp/output.err | grep 'Monitor is Off')"

then reboot and check the file /tmp/output.err

> SOLUTION

I don't have the exact solution for you. You will have to do some work and various reboots and error checks.
Oh.. I urge you to change the name of your script. You named it **poweroff** and so did I, forgetting it is a system command. So guess what happend when I ran my script...

Ok, first action.
In the top of your script add:

> export DISPLAY=:0.0
>   env > /tmp/output.log

Within the **while-loop** add

> sleep 5

command to prevent a huge /tmp/output.err file.

Reboot your system and check the output files in /tmp. If there is an empty output.err, then the **xset** command did not fail. If it did fail, you need to define more environment variables in your script. Perhaps one or more of the XDG_ variables, sorry but I'm not very experienced with X11.
Good luck !